# Data structure for Hungarian Rings in Haskell

Tags: haskell, data-structures

So I'm working on a solver for the Hungarian Rings puzzle in Haskell (https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/rings.htm)
I'm not great at the language, still have a lot of blind spots. I'm struggling to figure out what data structure to use to represent the puzzle, and would love any hints, tips or answers for this! (btw how my current idea represents the coloured balls is as a series of numbers that will be in order when the puzzle is solved)

Comment: You link is not working (probably because of my proxy). Can you describe puzzle here.

Comment: First impression: use four double-ended queues, one for each segment.  I believe okasaki ("purely functional data structures") has a good pure deque.

Answer (score 0):

Much like [how to represent a Rubik's cube in a data structure](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/142760/how-to-represent-a-rubiks-cube-in-a-data-structure), a naive model contains redundant information, and the most compact model depends on an [algebraic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube_group) of the object. So on the one hand, an operation on a model with redundant information may be inefficient, and an operation on a compact model (e.g. a permutation group) may be quite abstract when translating to physical operations.

So you may find that a permutation group of a higher order more easily describes it; here's from the Rubik's Cube Group article on Wikipedia:

> The Rubik's Cube group is the subgroup of the symmetric group *S₄₈* generated by the six permutations corresponding to the six clockwise cube moves.

And that might well correspond to a set of double-ended queues as luqui suggests, as long as you take into account that one rotating operation of one queue affects the other queues.